# Azure Active Directory Login to ubuntu laptop (or domain join)

Tags: azure, authentication, ubuntu

Is there a way to do AAD auth from a random linux machine?
It seems to be easy if you have Azure hosted VM, but can't seem to find any info, if it is possible for non-azure vm or laptop etc.

I thought this could be solved with ADDS, but that also does not seem to be answer if I do not have on-site domain server.

I have roaming ubuntu laptops and would like to get AAD login for them if possible.

Answer (score -1):

John Savill goes through this pretty thoroughly here:
[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AQeYKk9uGCg)

He says RBAC is a pre-requisite to AAD auth so no this won't work unless it's in azure.